# Django __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I'm have a problem with Django. I'm trying to create a second page in Django but get `TypeError`. I need help finding where I made the mistake.  I tried to read the documentation, but it's hard to me now.

**__init__.py**

```
default_app_config = 'page.apps.PageConfig'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index' ),
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView, name='index'),
]
```

**view.py**

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from libs.views import CachedViewMixin
from .models import Page


class IndexView(CachedViewMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'main/index.html'
    config = None
```

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _, ugettext
from solo.models import SingletonModel


class Page(SingletonModel):
    updated = models.DateTimeField(_('change date'), auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        default_permissions = ('change',)
        verbose_name = _('settings')

    def __str__(self):
        return ugettext('Home page')
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class PageConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'page'
    verbose_name = _('Another page')
```

Comment: Add the full traceback with the Django version you are using

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try add as_view and better to show full error trace

```
urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index' ),
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    #                          ^^^^^^^^
]
```